# MongoDB request by array of _ids (is it possible?)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

For example I have **n** documents:

```
{ _id : 1 }
{ _id : 2 }
{ _id : 3 }
...
{ _id : n }
```

By some logic I got array of **m** _ids: [1, 30, 500, 1001, ..., i ];

Is it possible to make ONE request using array of _ids for retrieving Cursor of these **m** documents? I do not want to make separate requests like:

`db.things.findOne({_id:1});`

`db.things.findOne({_id:30});`

`db.things.findOne({_id:500});`

`db.things.findOne({_id:1001});`

...

`db.things.findOne({_id:i});`

And if it is possible, how do that on JavaScript Shell and with official C# driver?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
c = db.things.find({_id:{$in:[1,30,500,1001,...,i]}})
```

Comment: Not only is this the correct, it will also be very efficient.

Comment: Note that using a large array with `$in` this is effectively equivalent to running many independent queries, and can still be slow if the list is long.

Comment: It'll always be faster due to reduced bandwidth usage between mongo and client. But you are correct. $in has an O(n) performance profile meaning that it will get linearly slower as n increases.

Comment: Will this return the results in the right order, i.e. according to the order in the $in-list, regardless of insert order and numeric values?

Answer (score 0):

And to do this with the C# Driver:

```
var documentIds = new BsonValue[] { ObjectId.Parse("id1"),  ObjectId.Parse("id2")}; 
var query = Query.In("_id", documentIds);
```